# Perform multi-field / multi-dimensional aggregations with nested fields in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am tracking attendance of few students. I am storing their details in the index like the below.

Each doc in "entries" have few other fields. The following data shows that a student has attended 6 classes on "Monday".

"entries" is of type "nested"

```
     {
      reg_id: 1111,
      "entires" : [
        {
          id: "123"
          day: 'Monday'
        },
        {
          id: "1234",
          attendance: true
        },
        {
          id: "12345",
          classes_attended: 6
        }
      ],
    }
```

I want the count of each classes_attended of students for each day.

For Example "72 entries of students found for "Monday", who has attended 6 classes"

Sample desired output - This is just a sample I am completely fine if the output schema is changed.

```
    [
      {
        "day" : "monday", 
        "classes_attended": 6,
        count: 4
      },
      {
        "day" : "monday", 
        "classes_attended": 1,
        count: 5
      },
      {
        "day" : "tuesday", 
        "classes_attended": 5,
        count: 2
      },
      {
        "day" : "tuesday", 
        "classes_attended": 6,
        count: 1
      }
    ]
```

Not sure How to start with the aggregations query:

I tried with the following query but I know its not the correct solution

```
"aggs": {
    "attendance_aggs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "entries"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "days": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "entries.day"
          },
          "aggs": {
          "attended": {
            "reverse_nested": {},
            "aggs":{
              "class_attended_day": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "entries.classes_attended"
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "class_attended_days_count": {
                    "reverse_nested": {},
                    "aggs": {
                      "classes_attended_final": {
                        "cardinality": {
                          "field": "entries.class_attended"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what the top-level object is so I'm going to assume it's a "student attendance entry per day". I'm also unsure what the `entries.ids` represent but I'll assume you'll be needing them at some later point so I'll keep them untouched.

Now, since all that your `entries` objects have in common is the `id`, they can be decoupled. Meaning that you should be using [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects) if any only if you **share some attributes** across all objects which need their **attribute connections preserved**. Since I don't see `entries.id` anywhere in your aggs, I'd recommend the following adjustments to your mapping:

```
PUT students
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "day": {                ------------
        "type": "keyword"                |
      },                                 |
      "attendance": {                    |                                
        "type": "boolean"                | <--
      },                                 |
      "classes_attended": {              |
        "type": "integer"                |
      },                     ------------
      "entries": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "day": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "copy_to": "day"               <--
          },
          "attendance": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "copy_to": "attendance"        <--
          },
          "classes_attended": {
            "type": "integer",
            "copy_to": "classes_attended"  <--
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here's your query:

```
GET students/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "days": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "classes_attended": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "classes_attended"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "student_count": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "_id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response can then be post-processed into whatever you prefer.

---

EDIT

You could hijack `reverse_nested` but will need to come back to it as you're referencing other nested entries:

```
GET students/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "attendance_aggs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "entries"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "days": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "entries.day"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "attended": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggs": {
                "class_attended_day": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "entries"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "class_attended_day": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "entries.classes_attended"
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "classes_attended_final": {
                          "cardinality": {
                            "field": "entries.classes_attended"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. I have a key "submit_id" that is shared with all the nested objects. Is it possible to stick with the nested type itself and rewrite the query. I am ready to change the index mapping as well. But FYI i am using an key that is shared across all the nested objects. It would be great if I am able to get the query without changing the mapping.

Comment: Added a nested version to my answer. But just to be clear -- I did not modify your nested-ness. I flattened the attributes onto the top-level because you don't need nested aggs to arrive at your answer.